# Populating two select tags in PHP from MySQL and cancelling entry selected in first tag

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am a student working on a php app. I am basically populating two select tags that are populated from mysql using the following code

I have one more select tag which deals with arrival location.

Here's an image:

[image: x]

The problem I am facing is I don't want the entry selected in the first select tag to be displayed in the second select tag as it is a journey between two locations.
I have no idea where to start, it would be a big help if someone can point me in the right direction.

```
<?php
// perform database query
$query = "SELECT id, municipality FROM airports";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

if(!$result){
  die("Database query failed.");
}
// only for syntax errors
// Select query for arrival
echo "<select name='arrival'>";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
    unset($id, $name);
    $id = $row['id'];
    $name = $row['municipality'];
    echo '<option value="'.$name.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}
echo "</select>";
// release returned data
mysqli_free_result($result);
?>
```

Comment: Use JS and check if the destination == arrival, if so prompt the user to change.

Comment: I'd prefer the entry selected in first select tag not getting displayed in the second tag

Comment: Then you could either remove it with JS... or make an ajax request to populate the second list with options that aren't the first. `SELECT id, municipality FROM airports where id <> ?` and pass the `id` not `name`, from the `option`.

Comment: Okay thanks, I'll give it a try

Comment: Where you store departure value in code so use that  in if  else loop  departure'value not match with `$row[municipality]` than append option tag

Comment: This kind of thing is a doddle if you use a JS framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i were you, i will use `javascript/jquery'`s ajax for easy playing with this kind of situation. My solutions is, for the first `select` element, you just fetching all the data coming from database and put them inside `1st select` element. Then this part, ajax will helping you.

The flow is :

1. Fetch all the data from php and populating data into 1st select element. Make it's value store the ID of data
2. Register `onChange` event on 1st select box, listen the event, and get the value(ID).
3. Inside `onChange` event again, do the `POST Ajax request`, sending the data(ID) together to server side code.
4. Do the database operation selecting the data which not include the sending ID. eg : `select *from tableName where id NOT IN(Id_that_we_sent)`
5. Sending data(response) back, and populating data into second select element

I'm bet, there is another workaround you can implement. But here is the approach that you can use. The choice is yours. :)

Comment: This is an OK answer, but the faster way if you're using Javascript to manipulate the lists would be to get the whole set of airports once at the beginning, store it as JSON and then use jQuery to add and remove the option elements, instead of asking the database again every time.

Also, I hate people who nag about stuff like I'm about to do, but your school should really be teaching you to use PDO to prepare statements instead of mysqli. I don't get that.

Comment: Yes, so many things to speed up the performance either cache the result using any caching like redis, memchached or whatever. But for make it running, doing step above is enough. Another, OP can practice and reading further to improve knowledge